# trying to delete a file called search protect

Tags: windows-7

have a file called, search protect, which I am trying to delete but cannot. every time I try a message comes up and says, You do not have sufficient access to uninstall Search Protect. Please contact you system administrator. I have gone into the file properties to try and change the administrator but am not allowed to. please help me in trying to get rid of this file. I have windows 7 home premium. thanks

Comment: Where is this file? Also, have a look at these results - https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+remove+search+protect

Comment: It appears that Search Protect is malware: http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Conduit-Search-Protect

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is also end task whenever it starts if your not admin then you are not administered to uninstall this. all you can do is to stop its process ATM while you work.

Here is a answer I am sure this is what your looking for: 
http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Conduit-Search-Protect

Answer (score 0):

Just did a removal using an adaptation of the technique showed in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKBpNCgfoTw

The exact technique shown in the video did not work for me, because, after clicking on UNINSTALLSTRING, the pathname of the file did not start with a slash.

So here is what I did:

1) Follow the first part of the video, up to and including the step of double-clicking on UninstallString

2) This will show a pathname.  If the pathname starts with a slash, go ahead and follow the rest of the video, and you're done.

3) If the pathname does not start with a slash (the case that I encountered) then delete the initial quotation mark of the pathname.  The video shows how to do this.

4) Go back to the Windows "Uninstall Programs" window and double-click on SEARCHPROTECT.  Windows will tell you that an error occurred, and ask if you want to remove the program anyway.  Say OK, and you're done!

It seems that if the double-clicking-to-uninstall raises an error, then Windows will uninstall if you agree.

Big thanks to the maker of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Had to deal with this one earlier today, discovered the issue is file permissions. As an administrator, browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\SearchProtect\Main\bin then find uninstall.exe. Right-Click the file and select Properties. On the Security Tab, select your user profile, click edit then check the Allow box under Full Control. Click ok to save the settings. Once that is done, the uninstall option will work removing all the files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution for deleting Windows files that do not like to be deleted, you could boot from Linux. If you don't have Linux installed, you can easily go to the Ubuntu website and follow instructions on how to make a Ubuntu USB stick. Then locate your hard drive in the file manager, click it to mount it, and search through your files to find the file you want to delete. This way you should haven no issue deleting the file, and with Ubuntu this works so similar to Windows that no specific Linux skills are needed either.